# Google map not displayed

Tags: css, google-maps

It used to work  just fine ...
But recently I've just changed my wordpress theme, and not the google map isn't displayed anymore.
And I can't figure out why ...

Here is the link for the search form: http://www.propertycrunch.co.uk/properties-search/
Enter an address and click find. It will list the properties, but the map won't appear ...

I can't figure out why :-(

Any idea are more than welcome ...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you used any plugin to show google map?

Comment: no, no plugin were used at all.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a question about how to configure Wordpress with new themes?

Comment: yes, this is a programming question: the map isn't displayed, why?

Answer (score 0):

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'slider'** in /properties-result/:126

```
<!--  TEST JQUERY UI Slider -->
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
```

Comment: Andy, script removed, still no map :-(

Comment: @Olivier where is your script to create the google Map? I only see the maps api files includes.

Comment: the header includes the google map key / api / scripts. Then, I've got a page calling the header, building the map, calling the footer, and displaying it all.

Comment: @Oliver: ah you're creating the div#map after your maps script. Try creating the div before the map or start the script in an onload or jquery ready function

Comment: Thank you all. One silly mistake ... In my header, in the body tag, I forgot to put: onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider-range").slider is not a function
[Break On This Error] slide: function( event, ui ) {
```

Line 131. There is no slider included.

Comment: I've removed the script, still no map displayed :-(